# Laravel: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

So i was trying to make form post and for some reason this error keeps showing up, and only in this form that it happens i do my form in the same way.

My form is:

```
<form action="{{route('email')}}" >
  <div class="w3-section">
  <label>Nome</label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-section">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-section">
  <label>Mensagem</label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="Message" required>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token"  value="{{ csrf_token() }}" >
  <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-black w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane w3-margin-right"></i>Submeter</button>
</form>
```

and web.php:

```
Route::post('/email', [
  'uses' => 'FrontController@postEmail', 'as'=>'email'
]);
```

and the conde from the FrontController:

```
 public function postEmail(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'Name' => 'required|',
        'Email' => 'required|',
        'Message' => 'required'
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('levadas');
 }
```

Comment: I think It should be `<form method="POST" ...`

Comment: thanks i should have look with more attention.

Answer (score 1):

form method must be added as post.if you are not mentioning method then it will treat as GET request

```
    <form action="{{route('email')}}" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add the 'POST' method to your form.
- You also should add `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside your form as a field. Along with the other answers.

Why not use Laravel's `{{ Form::open() }}`?

Example:

```
{{ Form::open([
    'role' => 'form', 
    'url' => route('email'),    
    'method' => 'post',
]) }}

{{--- Your fields here ---}}

{{ Form::submit('Send', ['class' => 'form-submit', 'id' => 'form-submit']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

For reference, check https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html.